# Play framework 2.7 with scala going down

Tags: multithreading, scala, rest, playframework, akka

I have a play scala application running on play 2.7. this is used as a middleware for our frontend and it has rest end points.

Now I am running two different instances on cloud and using nginx and bound these two servers and load balance it with round robin.

Now I am having a problem that the servers goes down quite often i.e. 3 times a day and interesting thing is both server goes down at same time. When I looked at it says out of memory exception on the both servers. I tried to print javaheapdump for out of memory but getting no dump . I am still analysing the thread dump to figure out what might be the actual cause of my server going down but what pins me is why the two servers are going down at the same time.

Out of thread dump I see there are 7707 thread with sleeping state. here it is

```
"Connection evictor" #146 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 cpu=2.33ms elapsed=1822.02s tid=0x00007f8a840c4800 nid=0x194 waiting on condition  [0x00007f8a58a5e000]
  java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (sleeping)
        at java.lang.Thread.sleep(java.base@11/Native Method)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.IdleConnectionEvictor$1.run(IdleConnectionEvictor.java:66)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(java.base@11/Thread.java:834)
```

This what I see when server goes down

```
[35966.967s][warning][os,thread] Failed to start thread - pthread_create failed (EAGAIN) for attributes: stacksize: 1024k, guardsize: 0k, detached.
Uncaught error from thread [application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-1398Uncaught error from thread [application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-1395]: ]: unable to create native thread: possibly out of memory or process/resource limits reachedunable to create native thread: possibly out of memory or process/resource limits reached, shutting down JVM since 'akka.jvm-exit-on-fatal-error' is enabled for, shutting down JVM since 'akka.jvm-exit-on-fatal-error' is enabled for ActorSystem[ ActorSystem[applicationapplication]
]
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create native thread: possibly out of memory or process/resource limits reached
  at java.base/java.lang.Thread.start0(Native Method)
  at java.base/java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:803)
  at org.apache.http.impl.client.IdleConnectionEvictor.start(IdleConnectionEvictor.java:96)
  at org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder.build(HttpClientBuilder.java:1219)
  at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpClientUtil.createClient(HttpClientUtil.java:287)
  at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpClientUtil.createClient(HttpClientUtil.java:298)
  at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpClientUtil.createClient(HttpClientUtil.java:236)
  at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpClientUtil.createClient(HttpClientUtil.java:223)
  at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.<init>(HttpSolrClient.java:198)
  at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient$Builder.build(HttpSolrClient.java:934)
  at com.github.takezoe.solr.scala.SolrClient$.$anonfun$$lessinit$greater$default$2$1(SolrClient.scala:11)
  at com.github.takezoe.solr.scala.SolrClient.<init>(SolrClient.scala:14)
  at service.tvt.solr.SolrPolygonService.getSuburbBoundary(SolrPolygonService.scala:212)
  at service.tvt.search.OrbigoSearchService.mapfeeder(OrbigoSearchService.scala:54)
  at service.bto.business_categories.MeedssCountService.$anonfun$suburbMeedssCount$2(MeedssCountService.scala:81)
  at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:287)
  at service.bto.business_categories.MeedssCountService.suburbMeedssCount(MeedssCountService.scala:80)
  at controllers.bto.industry_categories.meedss.MeedssController.$anonfun$suburbMeedssCount$1(MeedssController.scala:38)
  at play.api.mvc.ActionBuilder.$anonfun$apply$11(Action.scala:368)
  at scala.Function1.$anonfun$andThen$1(Function1.scala:52)
  at play.api.mvc.ActionBuilderImpl.invokeBlock(Action.scala:489)
  at play.api.mvc.ActionBuilderImpl.invokeBlock(Action.scala:487)
  at play.api.mvc.ActionBuilder$$anon$9.invokeBlock(Action.scala:336)
  at play.api.mvc.ActionBuilder$$anon$9.invokeBlock(Action.scala:331)
  at play.api.mvc.ActionBuilder$$anon$10.apply(Action.scala:426)
  at play.api.mvc.Action.$anonfun$apply$2(Action.scala:98)
  at play.api.libs.streams.StrictAccumulator.$anonfun$mapFuture$4(Accumulator.scala:184)
  at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:209)
  at play.api.libs.streams.StrictAccumulator.$anonfun$mapFuture$3(Accumulator.scala:184)
  at akka.stream.impl.Transform.apply(TraversalBuilder.scala:159)
  at akka.stream.impl.PhasedFusingActorMaterializer.materialize(PhasedFusingActorMaterializer.scala:515)
  at akka.stream.impl.PhasedFusingActorMaterializer.materialize(PhasedFusingActorMaterializer.scala:450)
  at akka.stream.impl.PhasedFusingActorMaterializer.materialize(PhasedFusingActorMaterializer.scala:443)
  at akka.stream.scaladsl.RunnableGraph.run(Flow.scala:629)
  at play.api.libs.streams.Accumulator$.$anonfun$futureToSink$2(Accumulator.scala:262)
  at scala.concurrent.Future.$anonfun$flatMap$1(Future.scala:303)
  at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise.$anonfun$transformWith$1(Promise.scala:37)
  at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:60)
  at play.api.libs.streams.Execution$trampoline$.execute(Execution.scala:72)
  at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.executeWithValue(Promise.scala:68)
  at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.dispatchOrAddCallback(Promise.scala:312)
  at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.onComplete(Promise.scala:303)
  at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise.transformWith(Promise.scala:36)
  at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise.transformWith$(Promise.scala:34)
  at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.transformWith(Promise.scala:183)
  at scala.concurrent.Future.flatMap(Future.scala:302)
  at scala.concurrent.Future.flatMap$(Future.scala:302)
  at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.flatMap(Promise.scala:183)
  at play.api.libs.streams.Accumulator$.$anonfun$futureToSink$1(Accumulator.scala:261)
  at akka.stream.impl.Transform.apply(TraversalBuilder.scala:159)
  at akka.stream.impl.PhasedFusingActorMaterializer.materialize(PhasedFusingActorMaterializer.scala:515)
  at akka.stream.impl.PhasedFusingActorMaterializer.materialize(PhasedFusingActorMaterializer.scala:450)
  at akka.stream.impl.PhasedFusingActorMaterializer.materialize(PhasedFusingActorMaterializer.scala:443)
  at akka.stream.scaladsl.RunnableGraph.run(Flow.scala:629)
  at play.api.libs.streams.SinkAccumulator.run(Accumulator.scala:144)
  at play.api.libs.streams.SinkAccumulator.run(Accumulator.scala:148)
  at play.core.server.AkkaHttpServer.$anonfun$runAction$4(AkkaHttpServer.scala:441)
  at akka.http.scaladsl.util.FastFuture$.strictTransform$1(FastFuture.scala:41)
  at akka.http.scaladsl.util.FastFuture$.$anonfun$transformWith$3(FastFuture.scala:51)
  at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:60)
  at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$AbstractBatch.processBatch(BatchingExecutor.scala:55)
  at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch.$anonfun$run$1(BatchingExecutor.scala:92)
  at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:12)
  at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$.withBlockContext(BlockContext.scala:81)
  at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch.run(BatchingExecutor.scala:92)
  at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:41)
  at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator.scala:49)
  at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
  at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
  at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
  at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
```

Any quick pointers will be really helpful

Comment: It looks like a resource leak for some network socket or threading stuff.

Comment: Hello Andriy, thanks for the comment. could you please guide me how can i catch the   problem

Comment: From the looks of it, I suspect that Solr is set up to use a thread per request and you're not closing the connections and freeing up threads, leading to OOM.  It looks like you're using the takezoe solr-scala-client and creating a new client per connection, in which case you should shut the client down when the request completes.

Comment: To start, are your Controllers/Services/Connectors etc annotated as `@Singleton` correctly? This could help with the "spinning up a new one with every request" issue.

Comment: [Read more on Singleton here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.7.x/ScalaDependencyInjection#Singletons) - it's normally a good place to start with Play application memory issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Levi Ramsey was right it was because of TakeZoe lib which we were using. We were creating client for every new request and not closing it. Finally we created a connection pool with limited active connections and it worked.